# How to change 802.1x settings for Wireless in Windows XP SP3?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ieee802.1x

I want to configure EAP-TLS with Machine Authentication ONLY for a wireless network. The supplicant is the bulit-in supplicant in Windows XP SP3.

I found the following document: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929847

-> `How to enable computer-only authentication for a 802.1X-based network in Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, and in Windows XP Service Pack 3`

But unforunately the needed command "`netsh wlan`" is not available in Windows XP -> "`Note Windows XP SP3 and earlier versions of Windows XP do not support the netsh wlan command.`"

How can I change the settings without the "`netsh wlan`" command?

Thanks,
mspoerr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the whole document :(

-> `To set the value of the AuthMode registry entry for Windows XP SP3 wireless connections, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.`
   ....

Thanks,
mspoerr

Comment: Good you fixed your problem! :p